# Why does these two injects give the same output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, inject

Why is the output the same?

First inject:

```
puts (3...10).inject(0) { |sum, x| (x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) ? sum + x : sum }
# => 23
```

Second inject:

```
puts (3...10).inject { |sum, x| (x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) ? sum + x : sum }
# => 23
# Why not 26?
```

I thought if there is no argument passed to it, inject uses the first element of the collection as initial value.

So the second inject should return the same value as this one:

```
puts (3...10).inject(3) { |sum, x| (x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0) ? sum + x : sum }
# => 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#inject() with an argument:

result = (3...10).inject(0) do |sum, x| 
  puts "#{sum} <-- #{x}: sum = #{sum+x}"
  sum + x
end 

--output:--
0 <-- 3: sum = 3
3 <-- 4: sum = 7
7 <-- 5: sum = 12
12 <-- 6: sum = 18
18 <-- 7: sum = 25
25 <-- 8: sum = 33
33 <-- 9: sum = 42
```

...

```
#inject without an argument:

result = (3...10).inject() do |sum, x| 
  puts "#{sum} <-- #{x}: sum = #{sum+x}"
  sum + x
end 

--output:--
3 <-- 4: sum = 7
7 <-- 5: sum = 12
12 <-- 6: sum = 18
18 <-- 7: sum = 25
25 <-- 8: sum = 33
33 <-- 9: sum = 42
```

> I always thought it takes the first element of the collection as
>   initial value and still performs the first iteration

The first iteration uses arr[0] as the sum and arr[1] as the first x.  When you don't provide an argument for inject(), it's equivalent to doing this:

```
data = (3...10).to_a
initial_sum = data.shift

data.inject(initial_sum) do |sum, x|
  puts "#{sum} <-- #{x}: sum = #{sum+x}"
  sum + x
end

--output:--
3 <-- 4: sum = 7
7 <-- 5: sum = 12
12 <-- 6: sum = 18
18 <-- 7: sum = 25
25 <-- 8: sum = 33
33 <-- 9: sum = 42
```

Answer (score 5):

> Why does these two injects give the same output in ruby?

... Because they're supposed to. They only differ by the addition of a `0`.

> I thought if there is no argument passed to it, inject uses the first element of the collection as initial value.

It does. But it doesn't duplicate it.

Your first example receives these numbers:

```
0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Your second example receives these numbers:

```
3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

Adding `0` to the beginning doesn't affect the result, they're both 23, not 26 as you claim.

Your 3rd example returns 26 because it receives these numbers:

```
3, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

Comment: Isn't `sum` and `x` both = 3 in the second `inject`? So `sum` would be 6 in the second iteration. And `sum` = 0 and `x` = 3 in the first `inject`. So `sum` would be 3 in the second iteration.

Comment: I just tried something and figured it out. `inject` takes the first element of the collection and sets it to `sum` as result of the first iteration. I always thought it takes the first element of the collection as initial value and still performs the first iteration.

Comment: @phre `[1,2,3].inject { |sum,x| }` has `sum` of 1 and `x` of 2.